# Сompare all urls of the list of dictionaries with each other

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

I have a list of dictionaries:

```py
list = [
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.16', 'contour': {'test': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_jdbc-url': 'jdbc:sqlserver://diasoftGLtest.rccf.ru:49031;databaseName=DiasoftGLtest', 'ws_url': 'http://fssp-dev-dev-fa-glws.apps.test.k8s.rccf.ru/glws/glws'}}}},
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.12', 'contour': {'cards': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_url': 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://diasoftGLCards.rccf.ru:49064;databaseName=diasoftglCARDS', 'ws_url': 'http://fssp-dev-dev-fa-glws.apps.test.k8s.rccf.ru/glws/glws'}}}},
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.12', 'contour': {'gp': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_url': 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://diasoftGLGP.rccf.ru:49040;databaseName=diasoftglGP', 'ws_url': 'http://fssp-dev-dev-fa-glws.apps.test.k8s.rccf.ru/glws/glws'}}}},
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.16', 'contour': {'dev': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_jdbc-url': 'jdbc:sqlserver://diasoftGLtest.rccf.ru:49031;databaseName=DiasoftGLtest', 'ws_url': 'http://fssp-dev-dev-fa-glws.apps.test.k8s.rccf.ru/glws/glws'}}}},
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.18', 'contour': {'preprod': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_url': 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DiasoftGK-Hagl.rccf.ru:1433/DiasoftGL'}}}},
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.18', 'contour': {'preprodft': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_url': 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SRVDB253.rccf.ru:1433/DiasoftGLft'}}}},
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.18', 'contour': {'prod': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_url': 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DiasoftGK-Hagl.rccf.ru:1433/DiasoftGL'}}}}
]
```

How can I find the same url values for different contours for keys `key=db_diasoft_datasource_jdbc-url` or `key=db_diasoft_datasource_url` in Python?

For example:
urls `'http://fssp-dev-dev-fa-glws.apps.test.k8s.rccf.ru/glws/glws'` are equal for `test, cards, gp and dev`. `'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DiasoftGK-Hagl.rccf.ru:1433/DiasoftGL'` are equal for `preprod and prod`

I need to output `system`, `version`, `contour` and `urls` where there are identical urls.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if this helps because I don't quite understand the explenation of your problem but this algorithm gives you all the unique urls with key=db_diasoft_datasource_jdbc-url or key=db_diasoft_datasource_url and their contour like this:

```
{
  "jdbc:sqlserver://diasoftGLtest.rccf.ru:49031;databaseName=DiasoftGLtest": ["test", "dev"],
  "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://diasoftGLCards.rccf.ru:49064;databaseName=diasoftglCARDS": ["cards"],
  "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://diasoftGLGP.rccf.ru:49040;databaseName=diasoftglGP": ["gp"],
  "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://CLSDB3014.rccf.ru:1433/DiasoftGLnt": ["preprod"],
  "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SRVDB253.rccf.ru:1433/DiasoftGLft": ["preprodft"],
  "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DiasoftGK-Hagl.rccf.ru:1433/DiasoftGL": ["prod"]
}
```

code:

```
list = [
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.16', 'contour': {'test': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_jdbc-url': 'jdbc:sqlserver://diasoftGLtest.rccf.ru:49031;databaseName=DiasoftGLtest', 'ws_url': 'http://fssp-dev-dev-fa-glws.apps.test.k8s.rccf.ru/glws/glws'}}}},
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.12', 'contour': {'cards': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_url': 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://diasoftGLCards.rccf.ru:49064;databaseName=diasoftglCARDS', 'ws_url': 'http://fssp-dev-dev-fa-glws.apps.test.k8s.rccf.ru/glws/glws'}}}},
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.12', 'contour': {'gp': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_url': 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://diasoftGLGP.rccf.ru:49040;databaseName=diasoftglGP', 'ws_url': 'http://fssp-dev-dev-fa-glws.apps.test.k8s.rccf.ru/glws/glws'}}}},
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.16', 'contour': {'dev': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_jdbc-url': 'jdbc:sqlserver://diasoftGLtest.rccf.ru:49031;databaseName=DiasoftGLtest', 'ws_url': 'http://fssp-dev-dev-fa-glws.apps.test.k8s.rccf.ru/glws/glws'}}}},
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.18', 'contour': {'preprod': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_url': 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://CLSDB3014.rccf.ru:1433/DiasoftGLnt'}}}},
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.18', 'contour': {'preprodft': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_url': 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SRVDB253.rccf.ru:1433/DiasoftGLft'}}}},
    {'system': 'account-d84', 'version': '1.2.18', 'contour': {'prod': {'urls': {'db_diasoft_datasource_url': 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DiasoftGK-Hagl.rccf.ru:1433/DiasoftGL'}}}}
]

h = {}
for i in list:
    for j in i["contour"]:
        for k in i["contour"][j]["urls"]:
            if (k == "db_diasoft_datasource_jdbc-url" or k == "db_diasoft_datasource_url"):
                if i["contour"][j]["urls"][k] in h:
                    h[i["contour"][j]["urls"][k]].append(j)
                else:
                    h[i["contour"][j]["urls"][k]] = [(j)]
```